# IronPython - MissingMemberException trying to import xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: c#, python, xml

I'm not at all familiar with Python, hoping someone can help and guide me to find what's going wrong here.

This is the error message:

> MissingMemberException: 'LightException' object has no attribute 'etree'

This is the python code that throws it:
`import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET`

We're using IronPython 2.7.3 in a c# project, the python code is executed using our Execute() method:

    `private void Execute(string code, ScriptScope scope)
    {
        try
        {
            PythonByteCode compiled = (PythonByteCode)Compile(code, SourceCodeType.AutoDetect);
            compiled.Execute(scope);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new PythonParseException(e);
        }
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite easy. When you running your engine it does not know about default assemblies location (on my machine it is "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7"). So it is tries to get modules from current working directory and then - `Lib` subdirectory of working directory. Of course it cannot find modules there.
[image]

What you should do:

Get path of IronPython distribution. Actually you need `Lib` subdirectory content. May be you should think how to deploy it on target machine so your release version may also find it.

Add it to python search path using code below

```
string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(scriptPath);                       
ICollection<string> paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmptydir))
{
    paths.Add(dir);
}
else
{
    paths.Add(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
}
engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);
```